# iOS 8 - ProgressHUD for Reachability is never dismissing with internet connection

Tags: objective-c, ios8, reachability

I have this code in my AppDelegate.m file to check for an internet connection using Apple's Reachability library:

```
 reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"https://s3.amazonaws.com"];
    reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [ProgressHUD dismiss];
            NSLog(@"Reachable");
        });
    };
    reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [ProgressHUD show:@"Awaiting internet connection…" Interaction:NO];
            NSLog(@"Not reachable");
        });
    };
    [reach startNotifier];
    NSLog(@"Starting notifier in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
```

However, the ProgressHUD never dismisses **even when there is an internet connection**.  This is the NSLog output I receive when building and running onto my iOS  device.

```
2014-10-13 16:19:12.100 iPwnStore[2814:939245] Starting notifier in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
2014-10-13 16:19:12.158 iPwnStore[2814:939245] SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue() failed: Invalid argument
2014-10-13 16:19:12.159 iPwnStore[2814:939245] Application did become active, starting notifier
2014-10-13 16:19:12.176 iPwnStore[2814:939245] Not reachable
```

I am building this application for iOS 8, does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

**Edit:** For the ProgressHUD, I am using this: https://github.com/relatedcode/ProgressHUD

Comment: I am sure that there is an issue with `SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue` as you can see from the log you provided.

Comment: @DavidG Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Not yet, I will take a further look after work...

Answer (score 0):

View on which you loaded the HUD should be the same,

```
For ex,
        [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:**self.view** text:@"connecting..." animated:YES];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:**self.view** animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am using ProgressHUD (https://github.com/relatedcode/ProgressHUD), not MBProgressHUD for my project.

Comment: @RAStudios @Prabhoo `[ProgressHUD show:#<String>#];` shows until you call `[ProgressHUD dismiss];` or you show another ProgressHUD. So we need to dismiss the ProgressHUD view when the website is reachable. or when the application is not active I think.